# word sorting in a string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make a function that gets a string and a number from the user and then makes every words length the same as the number i got form the user and prints the new string.
for example :

```
abcd__efgh_i
number = 3
and i should get
abc_def_ghi

#include < stdio.h > 
void f(char * p, int n) {
    int i = 0, br = 0, d, m = 0, br1 = 0, g;
    while (p[i] != '\0') {
        if (p[i] != '\0') {
            br++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (br % n == 0) {
        d = (br / n) - 1;
    } else {
        d = (br / n);
    }
    g = br + d;
    char b[g];
    i = 0;
    while (p[i] == '\0') {
        if (p[i] == '\0') {
            while (p[i] == '\0') {
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            b[m] = '\0';
            m++;
            br1 = 0;
        }
        b[m] = p[i];
        m++;
        i++;
        br1++;
        if (m == g) {
            b[m] = '\0';
        }
    }

    printf("%s", b);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to fix your code indentation, so that it's readable.  Thanks!

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: it's not working as it should i am asking how to do it correctly this is my first time asking for help here so sry for any mistakes

Comment: First timer? Welcome to SO! Your status indicates you have not read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page yet. Please do so soon. For tips on how to ask a proper question, look in the [Helpcenter](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
shuffle (const char *str, unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int i = 0;

    // loop until the end of the string is found
    while (*str) {

        // Examine the current character. If it is not a space, output it
        // and increment the number of characters output so far in the current word
        if (*str != ' ') {
            putchar (*str);
            ++i;
        }

        // Move to the next character 
        ++str;

        // Check if we have output "n" characters so far. If so, output a space to 
        // separate words and reset the character count
        if (i == n) {
            putchar (' ');
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    // Put a single new line at the end
    putchar ('\n');
}

int
main () {
    shuffle ("abcd  efgh   i jk", 3);
}
```

Comment: No explanation? Copy + Paste = Understanding?

Comment: I think the comments explain what is going on pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(const char * p, int n) {
    char b[n+1];
    int i=0;
    while(*p){
        if(*p == ' '){
            ++p;
            continue;//skip
        }
        b[i++] = *p++;
        if(i % n == 0){
            b[i] = '\0';//move out from loop
            printf("%s ", b);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```